# How can I change a base64 application/pdf file name?

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64, html-object

The API I am calling returns me a string like **'JVBERi0xL....(more)'**

And I am setting the result value to a variable **pdfFile** like

```
var file = "data:application/pdf;base64,"+res.data.result;
// here res.data.result = 'JVBERi0xL....(more)'
this.pdfFile = file;
```

**And my Html code is**

```
<object :data="pdfFile" name='test' type="application/pdf"  width="100%" height="800px"></object>
```

Like this, I can show the pdf on the browser but failed to change the name of the pdf file.

**Help:** 
I need to change the name marked with red.

[image: I need to change the name marked with red.]

**Added a larger image:** 
[Larger version of the previous image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVgN3.jpg)

Comment: Presumably that screenshot is from some sort of _download_ screen. How are you downloading the file?

Comment: The screenshot is of my browser screen where I am showing the pdf file.

Comment: Could you perhaps take a larger screenshot. It's unclear where the filename is being applied. What actually happens in order to get to the image in your question?

Comment: Ah never mind, I see now. It's how Chrome renders the `<object>` tag.

Comment: I found a duplicate but I don't think you're going to like it, sorry :(

Comment: Added a larger image. Perhaps you check.

Comment: Is there any way to do this, i am stucking with the same and not found any solution even in the questions which showing duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

The base64 representation of the file only contains the content of the file, but not the file name. But you can manually assign a file name this way:

```
function download() {
    const source = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'+res.data.result;
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    const fileName = 'file.pdf';

    downloadLink.href = source;
    downloadLink.download = fileName;
    downloadLink.click();
}
```

Comment: What makes you think OP is using an `<a>` tag?

Comment: Oh, you're right

Comment: Tried this. It can change the file name when I am downloading the file. But I want to show the name on my screen itself.

Comment: Oh I see.. If you want the name to show, why not you bind the name to your view?